# Getting Java Play framework to cache Ebean entities using memcached

Tags: java, playframework, memcached, ebean, playframework-2.6

I am running [Java Play framework](https://www.playframework.com) version v2.6.1 and using [Ebean](http://ebean-orm.github.io/) for persistence. My intention is to get [bean caching](http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/features/l2caching/using-bean-cache) going using [play2-memcached](https://github.com/mumoshu/play2-memcached) plugin.

**What have I done so far?**

- installed `memcached` on localhost and enabled verbose logging.
- replaced `ehcache` dependency with `cacheApi` in `libraryDependencies` in `build.sbt` (this, I assume, should remove Ehcache completely).
- added `"com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached-play26" % "0.9.0",` to `libraryDependencies` in `build.sbt`
- added `"Spy Repository" at "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2",` to `resolvers` in `build.sbt`
- added following entries to application conf:

`play.modules.disabled += "play.api.cache.ehcache.EhCacheModule"
play.modules.enabled+="com.github.mumoshu.play2.memcached.MemcachedModule"
play.cache.defaultCache=default
play.cache.bindCaches=["db-cache", "user-cache", "session-cache"]
memcached.host="127.0.0.1:11211"`

- took my entity and made it implement `Serializable`, also added `@com.avaje.ebean.annotation.Cache` annotation.
- enabled SQL logging

**What works?**

- loading entity with `Entity.find.byId(id)` results SQL `SELECT`. Loading it again with different request results no SQL statements.
- opening browser to localhost:11211 shows errors in syslog -- this is to make sure memcached is running and I can see requests appearing
- making memory dump I can see that cache related classes from `com.github.mumoshu` are loaded.

**What doesn't work?**

- I expect cached objects to be sent to memcached (on read and/or update). This is not happening - there are no memcached logs related to this. Neither there are any connections to port 11211 if I run `netstat -na | grep 11211`.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried using CacheStrategy annotation instead of the Cache annotation? This talks about the CacheStrategy annotation: http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/features/l2caching/using-bean-cache

Comment: `@CacheStrategy` is renamed to `@Cache`. https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/684

Answer (score 1):

You also need to bind `javax.caching.CacheManager`.
Add

```
libraryDependencies += jcache
```

to your `build.sbt`.

If you are using Guice, you have to add the following for Java annotations as well:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.jsr107.ri" % "cache-annotations-ri-guice" % "1.0.0"
```

More information can be found in the "JCache Support" section of the Playframework documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCache#JCache-Support).